# ObjC blocks & openssl C callbacks

Tags: objective-c, ios, callback, openssl, block

Have a simple one-off tasks which needs a progress bar. OpenSSL has a useful
callback which one can use for that:

```
rsa=RSA_generate_key(bits,RSA_F4,progressCallback,NULL);
```

with

```
static void callback(int p, int n, void *arg) {
    .. stuff
```

However I want to call this from ObjectiveC without too much ado:

```
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Generating CSR";

    [self genReq:^(int p,int n,void *arg) {
            hud.progress = --heuristic to guess where we are --
    } completionCallback:^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }];
```

With Genrec: as an objC method:

```
-(void)genReq:(void (^)(int,int,void *arg))progressCallback 
      completionCallback:(void (^)())completionCallback 
{
    .....
    rsa=RSA_generate_key(bits,RSA_F4,progressCallback,NULL);
    assert(EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey,rsa));
    rsa=NULL;
    ....

   completionCallback();
}
```

Now completionCallback(); works splendidly and as expected. But I get a compiler warning/error which I cannot quell for the progress callback:

```
 Passing 'void (^__strong)(int, int, void *)' to parameter of incompatible type 'void (*)(int, int, void *)'
```

So am curious -- what is the appropriate way to do this ?

Thanks,

Dw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**All code is just typed into this answer, test carefully before using!**

Function pointers and blocks are not the same thing; the former is just a reference to code, the latter is a closure containing both code and an environment; they are not trivially interchangeable.

You can of course use function pointers in Objective-C, so that is your first option.

If you wish to use blocks then you need to find a way to wrap a block and pass it as a function reference...

The definition of `RSA_generate_key` is:

```
RSA *RSA_generate_key(int num,
                      unsigned long e,
                      void (*callback)(int,int,void *),
                      void *cb_arg);
```

The fourth argument can be anything and is passed as the third argument to the callback; this suggests we could pass the *block* along with a pointer to a C function which calls it:

```
typedef void (^BlockCallback)(int,int);

static void callback(int p, int n, void *anon)
{
   BlockCallback theBlock = (BlockCallback)anon; // cast the void * back to a block
   theBlock(p, n);                               // and call the block
}

- (void) genReq:(BlockCallback)progressCallback 
         completionCallback:(void (^)())completionCallback 
{
   .....
   // pass the C wrapper as the function pointer and the block as the callback argument
   rsa = RSA_generate_key(bits, RSA_F4, callback, (void *)progressCallback);
   assert(EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey,rsa));
   rsa = NULL;
   ....

   completionCallback();
}
```

And to invoke:

```
[self genReq:^(int p, int n)
             {
                hud.progress = --heuristic to guess where we are --
             }
      completionCallback:^{
                            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                          }
];
```

Whether you need any bridge casts (for ARC) is left as an exercise!

Comment: Most Lovely ! And __bridge is all that is needed for ARC. Shame that one needs to have the callback() in between - i.e. that one cannot pass the progressCallback as a (void (*)(int, int, void *)) from its void (^__strong)(int, int, void *) directly.

Comment: @Dirk-WillemvanGulik - the only reasonable way to support automatic passing of a block, i.e. closure (code pointer + environment), as a function pointer (just a code pointer) would be to dynamically generate code stubs; and that has various drawbacks. The common pattern in C is to specify a function pointer taking an extra value, usually of type `void *`, that can be used to pass a user-defined environment and thus manually construct a closure - and openssl follows that pattern and the solution above just uses it.

Comment: Clear. Thanks (again!). Have dug into NSStackBlock and makes total sense.