# How to pass a objective-c method to c function as callback?

Tags: objective-c

I've already read several articles about this question, but none of them solve my problem.

Briefly, in my NSApplicationDelegate, I called a function `pcap_loop`, `pcap_loop` needs a function pointer as callback, the callback signature is

`void got_packet(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *)`

I want to pass one of the NSApplicationDelegate's method as callback, so I can use these data in my app, somebody suggest me using "SEL + IMP", but I can't pass the `self` to callback, also somebody suggest "block", not work.

So, any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use an Objective-C method for this? If it needs a C function, pass it a C function, period. You won't be able to do anything else in the lack of a `self` pointer.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is there anyway for me to get the NSApplicationDelegate instance in callback? I mean, something like [NSApplicationDelegate sharedInstance]

Comment: @MartinLuo In Cocoa : [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate], or [NSApp delegate]. And in iOS [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of what you require can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445295/objc-blocks-openssl-c-callbacks/10446279#10446279).

In your case you are calling `pcap_loop`:

```
int pcap_loop(pcap_t *p, int cnt, pcap_handler callback, u_char *user)
```

where `pcap_handler` is:

```
void got_packet(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *header, const u_char *packet);
```

Now the *last* argument to `pcap_loop`, `user`, is passed as the *first* argument to `got_packet`, `args` and can be anything you wish. This corresponds to the argument `cb_arg`/`anon` in the previous answer. Now just follow the previous answer, passing a block which invokes your `NSApplicationDelegate` method as `user` and the C function to invoke that block as `callback`.